# Bulk update XML records in SQL server

Tags: sql, xml, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to update loads of records which are stored as XML in my SQL Server 2008 database similar to this.

```
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Nike trainer 1</name>
    <description>Trainer 1</description>
    <price>10.99</price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Nike trainer 2</name>
    <description>Trainer 2</description>
    <price>15.99</price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Nike trainer 3</name>
    <description>Trainer 3</description>
    <price>16.99</price>
  </product>
</products>
```

I want to bulk update all my prices by 1.50 and as there are approx 900 products this would be very time consuming going through every product, so was wondering if there is a quick way of doing this via SQL statements?

Comment: Is your XML stored in a field that uses the xml data type?

Comment: You could update each product, but you'd have to do it in a loop rather than in a single statement, since `replace value of` can only operate on one node at a time.

Comment: That sounds feasible, do you have an example or point of reference?

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible ,you should use set XmlPart.modify() like-

set @value = 'val2'

set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/item/@value)[1] with "val2"')